# Explicitation of an equation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

We consider the function $f(x,y)=\arctan(x^2-y^2-1)$. Why into the neighborhood of $(1, 0)$, there exists a $x=g(y)$ but not a $y=h(x)$ that make explicit the equation $f(x,y)=0$? I think that the existance of $x$ follows from Dini's theorem, is it right?

Thank you

Comment: There should be something wrong in the question as $f(0,1) = \arctan(-2) \neq 0$.

Comment: Sorry, the point is (1,0)

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x,y)=\arctan\left(x^2-y(x)^2-1\right)=0$

compute the implicit derivative $y'(x)$. We have:

$$\frac{2x-2y(x)y'(x)}{1+\left(x^2-y(x)^2-1\right)^2}=0$$
and solving for $y'(x)$
$$2x-2y(x)y'(x)=0\to y'(x)=\frac{x}{y(x)}$$
so you can see that $y'(x)$ does not exist at $(1,0)$ and this is the reason why the implicit theorem can't be applied.

Comment: @MatthewPilling fixed! Thank you

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I understand the reasoning but I have a doubt. Why if it exists it must necessarily be derivable? Can't there be an implicit function without it being derivable at that point?

Comment: @Rick88 You're right. A map may exist and not be differentiable. My answer goes in that direction.

Comment: @Rick88 Here is the theorem I was talking about in my answer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Proof_for_2D_case

Answer (score 0):

The map $t \mapsto \tan t$ is a bijection from $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ onto $(-\infty, \infty)$ and $\tan(0)=0$. Therefore $f(x,y) = 0$ is equivalent to $r(x,y) = x^2-y^2-1 = 0$ in a neighborhood of $(1,0)$.

$r(x,y)=0$ is equivalent to

$$x_{\pm} = \pm \sqrt{1 + y^2}.$$ Around $x=1$, there is only one solution which is $x=\sqrt{1 + y^2}$. Which proves as requested the existence of $x=g(y)$.

On the other end the equation $y^2 = x^2-1$ has no solution for $x^2 \lt 1$. Therefore, the equation $f(x,y)$ can not be solved as $y = h(x)$ around $(1,0)$.

Comment: Thank you, it is clear!